# Issue in swapping of image on variation in Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce site that has a lot of variable products. All products have multiple images assign to the parent product but none to the variation one. I was expecting that this meant that when the variation changes it should stay to the selected page. This is not the case though as whenever I change a variation the main image change to the product image. This is counter intuitive and I am searching for a way to override this.

Comment: _"I was expecting that this meant that when the variation changes it should stay to the selected page"_ - may you please describe this part a lil bit more precise.

Comment: Please explain this better. It seems like you are saying that when you select a variant and the variant has no image, the parent product image is shown, but that is expected and desirable behavior. Use screenshots to show what is happening and then describe what you want to happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the variants you have, you may want to look at using a product configurator.  This will let you change the image to match the product, and give you the flexibility to have a number of different variable features.  Be warned, that creating the product artwork is much more complex for a configured product, since the image for each of the features are used to piece together the image for the configured product.  Each sub-component of the image that represents a variable component must be correctly aligned and scaled, and not conflict with other options.  The configurator from Iconic is a premium plugin, but they do have a free trial.

https://iconicwp.com/products/woocommerce-product-configurator/